# What algorithm does OpenCV's Bayer conversion use?

Tags: c++, c, opencv, cuda, gpu

I would like to implement a GPU Bayer to RGB image conversion algorithm, and I was wondering what algorithm the OpenCV `cvtColor` function uses. Looking at the source I see what appears to be a variable number of gradients algorithm and a basic algorithm that could maybe be bilinear interpolation? Does anyone have experience with this that they could share with me, or perhaps know of GPU code to convert from Bayer to BGR format?

The source code is in `imgproc/src/color.cpp`. I'm looking for a link to it. `Bayer2RGB_` and `Bayer2RGB_VNG_8u` are the functions I'm looking at.

Edit: Here's a link to the source.

http://code.opencv.org/projects/opencv/repository/revisions/master/entry/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp

I've already implemented a bilinear interpolation algorithm, but it doesn't seem to work very well for my purposes. The picture looks ok, but I want to compute HOG features from it and in that respect it doesn't seem like a good fit.

Comment: +1 for your name. Just kidding, good question. :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Default is 4way linear interpolation or variable number of gradients if you specify the VNG version.

see ..\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp for details.

I submitted a simple linear CUDA Bayer->RGB(A) to opencv, haven't followed if it's been accepted but it should be in the bugs tracker.
It's based on the code in [Cuda Bayer/CFA  demosaicing example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8072305/cuda-bayer-cfa-demosaicing-example).

Here is a sample of howto use cv::GPU in your own code.

```
/*-------RG ccd  BGRA output ----------------------------*/
 __global__ void bayerRG(const cv::gpu::DevMem2Db in, cv::gpu::PtrStepb out)  
{ 
    // Note called for every pair, so x/y are for start of cell so need x+1,Y+1 for right/bottom pair
    // R G 
    // G B 

    // src
    int x = 2 * ((blockIdx.x*blockDim.x) + threadIdx.x);
    int y = 2 * ((blockIdx.y*blockDim.y) + threadIdx.y);

    uchar r,g,b;        

    // 'R'
    r = (in.ptr(y)[x]);
    g = (in.ptr(y)[x-1]+in.ptr(y)[x+1]+(in.ptr(y-1)[x]+in.ptr(y+1)[x]))/4;
    b = (in.ptr(y-1)[x-1]+in.ptr(y-1)[x+1]+(in.ptr(y+1)[x-1]+in.ptr(y+1)[x+1]))/4;  
    ((uchar4*)out.ptr(y))[x] = make_uchar4( b,g,r,0xff);

    // 'G' in R 
    r = (in.ptr(y)[x]+in.ptr(y)[x+2])/2;
    g = (in.ptr(y)[x+1]);
    b = (in.ptr(y-1)[x+1]+in.ptr(y+1)[x+1])/2;
    ((uchar4*)out.ptr(y))[x+1] = make_uchar4( b,g,r,0xff);

    // 'G' in B
    r = (in.ptr(y)[x]+in.ptr(y+2)[x])/2;
    g = (in.ptr(y+1)[x]);
    b = (in.ptr(y+1)[x-1]+in.ptr(y+1)[x+2])/2;
    ((uchar4*)out.ptr(y+1))[x] = make_uchar4( b,g,r,0xff);

    // 'B' 
    r = (in.ptr(y)[x]+in.ptr(y)[x+2]+in.ptr(y+2)[x]+in.ptr(y+2)[x+2])/4;;
    g = (in.ptr(y+1)[x]+in.ptr(y+1)[x+2]+in.ptr(y)[x+1]+in.ptr(y+2)[x+1])/4;
    b = (in.ptr(y+1)[x+1]);
    ((uchar4*)out.ptr(y+1))[x+1] = make_uchar4( b,g,r,0xff);    
} 


/* called from */
extern "C" void cuda_bayer(const cv::gpu::DevMem2Db& img, cv::gpu::PtrStepb out)
{
    dim3 threads(16,16);    
    dim3 grid((img.cols/2)/(threads.x), (img.rows/2)/(threads.y));  

    bayerGR2<<<grid,threads>>>(img,out);    
    cudaThreadSynchronize();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm having a look at that now.

Comment: Notice a typo when calculating "B": in line `b = (in.ptr(y+1)[x-1]+in.ptr(y+1)[x+2])/2;`, blue cells are to the left and right to the green cell, therefore the index should be `x - 1` and `x + 1` (not `x + 2`). Here's the correct way `b = (in.ptr(y+1)[x-1]+in.ptr(y+1)[x+1])/2;`

Comment: In the code above, why do the 'R' and 'B' cases use 4 neighbors but the 2 'G' cases use only 2 neighbors?

Answer (score 2):

Currently, to my knowledge, the best debayer out there is DFPD (directional filtering with posteriori decision) as explained in [this paper](http://elynxsdk.free.fr/ext-docs/Demosaicing/todo/Menon_Andriani_IEEE_T_IP_2007.pdf). The paper is quite explanatory and you can easily prototype this approach on Matlab. Here's a [blog post](http://blog.cuvilib.com/2014/06/12/dfpd-debayer-on-gpu/) comparing the results of DFPD to debayer based on linear approach. You can visibly see the improvement in artifacts, colors and sharpness.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know at this point it is using adaptive homogeneity directed demosaicing. Explained in a paper by Hirakawa and many other sources on the web.